# Given $z = y^2 -2 x^2$, find $(\partial z / \partial x)_{r}$, where x, y and r, $\theta$ are rectangular and polar coordinates.

Tags: partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

I am a bit stuck with the notation and, thus, the calculations. I need to find the partial derivative of z with respect to x, keeping r constant.

So my solution would be:
$(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x})_{r} = (\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}) \cdot (\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}) + (\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}) \cdot (\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x})$

But because r is constant, $(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}) = 0$ and we are left with $(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}) \cdot (\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x})$

Substituting $x = rcos(\theta)$ and $y = rsin(\theta)$

$(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x})_{r} = - \frac{sin(\theta)}{r} \cdot (2r^2sin(\theta)cos(\theta) + 4r^2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)) = -6rsin^2(\theta)cos(\theta)$

Which is incorrect because the answer should be $-6x$.

Could you please tell me where is a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: Do not use `\times` ($\times$) for multiplication--especially in a multivariable setting. Use `\cdot` ($\cdot$) if you must use anything. $\times$ is used for cross products.

Comment: sorry for that, I editted my question

Comment: Should this be approached as doing the gradient in polar coordinates noting that $r$ is constant so $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} = 0$ and then dotting with $\hat{i}$? I was taking a similar approach to you and ended up with $\frac{6xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$ instead.